# Difficulty with magic bitboards

Tags: engines, programming, bitboard

I am having some difficulty with magic bitboards, in that multiple blocker bitboards **which would result in different attack boards** having the same index. I realize this is likely because of one of the following reasons:

1. The magics I am using are incorrect.
2. I am generating indexes incorrectly.
3. I am generating attack masks incorrectly.

I have tested my code relating to problems 2), and 3), finding it to be correct, as well as trying different sets of magics, however this has not worked. I would greatly appreciate any help. I have attached the relevant code (C++17), or refer to a set of working magics.

```
// to generate the attack sets
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
    int n = count1s(rookMasks[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < 1 << n; j++){
        ull bb = int2blocker(j, rookMasks[i]);
        int ind = index(bb,rookMagics[i],rookShift[i]);
        ull attack = rookMask(i,1,bb);
        blockedRookMasks[i][ind] = attack;
    }
    n = count1s(bishopMasks[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        ull bb = int2blocker(j, bishopMasks[i]);
        int ind = index(bb,bishopMagics[i],bishopShift[i]);
        ull attack = bishopMask(i,1,bb);
        blockedBishopMasks[i][ind] = attack;
    }
}
```

The magics and shifts I am using come from here https://github.com/goutham/magic-bits/blob/master/include/magic_bits.hpp (lines 108-191)